# Why learning rate is change in SOM with Iterations

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

Normally learning rate is a value that we decide in the begining and normally it doesn't change with no of iterations.
But in SOM learning rate is change with the iteration, what is the idea behind that?

As I understand learning rate should be decrease with the number of iterations. why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason is quite simple. SOMs are ill-designed in terms of mathematical models, and one needs to decrease learning rate in order to ensure convergence. In other words, if you do not change this value, learning procedure might not stop at all. This issue is somehow addressed by more mathematical models called "Principal Curves" and "Principal Manifolds", which are much less popular but introduce valid mathematical approach for learning SOM-like representations.

Comment: I know this was asked 3 years ago, but could you explain why we don't change the learning rate in MLP but we change it and keep decreasing it in every epoch in Kohonen's SOM? What do you mean by learning procedure might never stop if i wasn't decreased?

Comment: Not every iterative scheme has a convergence guarantee. SOM do not have it, unless learning rate is artificially moved quickly to 0, it simply means that the algorithm that was originally proposed does not have to stop otherwise. In MLPs people often do the same, under the name of "learning rate annealing", although for slightly different reasons.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me understand.

Comment: I have one more doubt, why don’t SoM’s not converge if the learning rate is kept constant? I keep trying to understand this, but im a bit confused. Would be of great help if you could help me out. Is there a specific reason they dont converge or was it found and established by trial and error?

Comment: Learning rates determine how much a map node "moves" in the output space, given a certain input. Think of it as putting in golf; If you could only hit the ball 1m in any direction, it would be hard to hit the hole. If you can gradually decrease the length of the put, you can increment closer to the hole.


If the learning rate is too high/ constantly high, then nodes will overshoot their goal positions. The next iteration will overshoot in a different direction. If you reduce the "jump length" each iteration however, you can get closer and closer to the goal, and eventually converge.